# cURL for Windows: how can I send multiple line command in a console?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am learning to use cURL and I need to run this in a console:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/library/book/_search?pretty=true -d {
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : { "query" : "title:crime" }
    }
}
```

But this is a multi-line command. How can I handle it to send a complete command?

Note that I understand I can put the content after -d in a file to run this command.

Comment: What’s keeping you from simply _removing_ the line breaks (as they are only _formatting_, and should not matter at all for the actual content of that JSON data structure) …?

Comment: _“I understand I can put the content after -d in a file to run this command”_ – quote cURL manual: _“When `--data` is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out”_ … so you would not have them in there in that case either.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks so much for chiming in. Should I put the JSON structure in one line such as curl -XGET localhost:9200/library/book/_search?pretty=true -d {"query" : {"match_all" : {}} or curl -XGET localhost:9200/library/book/_search?pretty=true -d @{"query" : {"match_all" : {}} ? I got error in the first case, warning in the second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341091/multiline-curl-command)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't find any way so far to send command spanning multiple using curl on windows. However, I was able to find a way to get the task done. Below is how I would rewrite the command you are trying to achieve

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/library/book/_search?pretty=true -d "{ \"query\" : { \"query_string\" : { \"query\" : \"title:crime\" }  } }"
```

Just make sure the `/library/book/` is right index name.

Hoping to hear back if you are able to make it

Answer (score 24):

Install **[Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win)** for windows. Use **git bash** to run the curl commands.

Comment: This was easy - it worked immediately and proved that the url, apikey and json all worked and returned the right answer.  Then I could focus on the Windows formatting differences.

Comment: Worked like a charm. No need to escape characters; just copy and paste as-is.

Answer (score 20):

Sometime I have to use windows, try something like this :

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_search -d^
"{^
    \"query\": {^
        \"query_string\": {^
            \"query\": \"year:2003\"^
        }^
    }^
}"
```

^ to extend a command to next line and
\" to escape " on the json

Comment: ^ works for me to add multiple lines when adding header items, etc.