# Multiline curl command

Tags: post, curl, request, http-post

I am trying to modify a curl request that was captured with Google Chrome Dev Tools.

Here is what the command looks like

```
curl "http://WEBSITE" -H "Host: WEBSITE" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1184875127259" --data-binary "-----------------------------1184875127259"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""FORM1"""^

"FORM1DATA"^
"-----------------------------1184875127259"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""FORM2"""^

"FORM2DATA"^
"-----------------------------1184875127259"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""FORM3"""^

"FORM3DATA"^
"-----------------------------1184875127259"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""embed"""^

"true"^
"---------------------------1184875127259--"^
""
```

`Form#` is the name of the form and `Form#Data` is the data I submitted in the forms.

How would I make this be a single line curl request I can just copy into my command line and have it do the same thing that my browser did?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**For Linux and MacOS:** Use the `\` escape character:

```
curl "http://WEBSITE" -H "Host: WEBSITE" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml \
,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
```

**For Windows:** Use the `^` escape character:

```
curl "http://WEBSITE" -H "Host: WEBSITE" ^
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml ^
,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
```

Comment: @DirkSchumacher, Instead of using \ for line escaping use ^ in windows. Back slash is for macOs.

Comment: @saini-arun : good hint!-) Thank you! Could have solved it by myself with little more cells in my brain... I just reflect for me that it is always good to share basic settings if I am aware that environmental issues could be considered.

Comment: For Windows, you can use caret (^) as suggested above. Example:

curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 9HqLlyZOugoStsXCUfD_0YdwnNnunAJF8V47U3QHXSq" ^
     -H "X-User-Id: aobEdbYhXfu5hkeqG" ^
     -H "Content-type:application/json" ^
     -d '{"avatarUrl": "http://domain.tld/to/my/own/avatar.jpg"}' ^
     http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.setAvatar

Comment: Note that if attempting to import a cURL request in as "Raw Text" in Postman, use Copy >> "Copy as cURL (bash)" in Chrome Dev Tools to get the request in the format that Postman expects.  "Copy as cURL (cmd)" uses the format that includes the ^ as line separator and Postman will throw an error reading: "Error while importing Curl: Only the URL can be provided without an option preceding it. All other inputs must be specified via options."

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Windows, I have found it easier to install Git and use Git Bash to run Curl. This was initially suggested in a separate article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567112/5636865.

Comment: I agree! Git Bash is the awesome when you are on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

> NOTE: watch out for the tendency to indent on multiple line commands,
>   as it will embed spaces and screw up the curl command.  the sed
>   command replaces embedded spaces within the variables with the %20
>   string so that spaces can be used embedded in the strings you pass as
>   variables

```
messageout="The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plains"
summaryout="This is a test record"
alertnameout="Test Alert"


curl -v -silent request POST "URL.com?\
summary=`echo $summaryout | sed -e 's/ /%20/g'`&\
alertname=`echo $alertnameout | sed -e 's/ /%20/g'`&\
message=`echo $messageout | sed -e 's/ /%20/g'`"
```

Answer (score 4):

The Windows equivalent to `\` is `^`.