# I would like to sent message by add new line in meassage via batch-file (curl)

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I create batch file to sent message to line notify.
I want new line in my message. I try to use \n, %0a but it can't use.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken" -F "message=Computer 1 sent message!" https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify
```

in `message=Computer 1 sent message!` I want output follow:

> Computer 1
>   sent message!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL for Windows: how can I send multiple line command in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556064/curl-for-windows-how-can-i-send-multiple-line-command-in-a-console)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, that should work

`curl -X "POST" "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken" \
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
     -d $'Computer 1 sent message!
Line1
Line2
Line3'`

Comment: This is cmd not bash/*nix-shell, the line continuation char is `^` not `\`